# Button click listener in a fragment

Tags: android, events, button, android-fragments

i know this question has been asked thousands of times, but i have this code and i have no idea it doesn't work. What i want to do is having a button in a fragment that when it is clicked, it has to show a toast.

```
public class MyFragment1 extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_fragment1, container, false);

    Button bot = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    bot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }


}
```

With this code literally nothing happens, it doesn't even show an error message. I've tried different solutions but none of them have solved the problem

Comment: You are just missing a call to the `show()` of the Toast. More explanation can be found in @Lal's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to show the `Toast`, So kindly show the Toast using `show()` like

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

There is actually no error, that is why you are not getting any error messages in your Logcat. Only thing is that you are not showing the `Toast`

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work. First thing i tried to do is to change the text in a editText but it didn't work either. The problem i'm facing is that the code inside the onclick block doesn't get executed

Comment: Dont you have an `onCreate()` ?